# Three20 TTTableViewController with multiple models? Is this possible?

Tags: iphone, three20

I may be building in the next few weeks a TTTableViewController where the data provided by the model will comes from multiple sources. Some of this will come from a Facebook FQL query and the other from a drupal site via the services module. I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this requirement while using TTURLRequest Model.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the data sources will be presented. Will the table have to merge the results or will you flip between the two sources? If it's flipping then you just need to reassign the datasource (or if you want to keep the same datasource, reassign the model of the datasource).

For one of my projects I presented the merger of two different models.  I created a model that was comprised of an array of models. I then had to implement each of the appropriate model methods in terms of the array of models. For example:

```
- (BOOL)isLoaded {
    BOOL isLoaded = YES;
    for (TTModel *model in self.models) {
        isLoaded &= model.isLoaded;
    }
    return isLoaded;
}

- (void)load:(TTURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy more:(BOOL)more {
    for (TTModel *model in self.models) {
        [model load:cachePolicy more:more];
    }
}

etc etc
```

This worked quite well for us, even when one of the models was based on local data and the other on data over the wire.